# Very weird, Android app crashes when ANY picture of a twenty euro note is inserted

Tags: android, image, background, crash

I'm working on an app that allows users to donate money to charity and as of right now the buttons for each amount show a picture of the note/coin. What's really weird is that it crashes whenever the image of a twenty euro note is displayed AND there is a background image. No background image it works fine. I've tried screenshotting the picture and using that in case the file was corrupted, using different pictures, trying different formats. It's always a 20 euro note that causes the problem, I can have 5 buttons of ten euro notes and everything works fine. Also the images I have tried for the twenty euro note have all been the same dimensions and size as the other, working buttons.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ie.jc.dare3.temp">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fiftyCent"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="94dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fifty_cent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/oneEuro"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="94dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/one_euro"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/twoEuro"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fiftyCent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.564" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/twoEuro"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="94dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/two_euro"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/twentyEuro"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="107dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/twenty"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tenEuro"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/tenEuro"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="107dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ten_euro"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fiveEuro"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fiveEuro"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="107dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/five_euro"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oneEuro"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502" />
```

Comment: What are the resolutions of each of the images you use?

Comment: there are two sizes; 286x150 (for notes and the one the image making the app crash uses) and 150x150 for coins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Android, so I wanted to add this as a comment - but I don't have enough reputation, so...

I may be barking up the completely wrong tree, but I noticed that for one attribute in your xml you have:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/twenty"
```

which differs from all the other tags where it has an underscore and unit, e.g.

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/five_euro"
```

So maybe you just have a typo and reference something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is actually an artifact left over from me trying every possible combination of things, including changing it from twenty_euro to twenty because I used a new image.